# Discord.js v12 role inquiry

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to develop a discord bot but I'm having some problems.

The purpose of my bot is to send a message to the text channel "YYYYYY" when my staff on my server join the voice channel named "XXXXXX"

My Code Block:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID;
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;
    if(newUserChannel === "838819904798457928" && newMember.roles.cache.has === "839532611948511272")
    { 
        console.log(" example entered "+newUserChannel);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Left the channel");
    }
});
```

My Error Code :

```
if(newUserChannel === "838819904798457928" && newMember.roles.cache.has === "839532611948511272")
                                                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `.has()` is a method, not a property. You need to pass a value into it. For example `newmember.roles.cache.has("839532611948511272")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `voiceStateUpdate` event doesn't return a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) it returns a [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState).

So in order to get the the member roles you'll have to get the member from the VoiceState first

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    console.log(newState.member.roles.cache);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I solved my problem and now it works fine.

I'm leaving the working code block here so that our friends who want to do this kind of operation or have problems can have a look and use it.

```code
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
 let newUserChannel = newState.channelID;
    if(newUserChannel === "838819904798457928" && newState.member.roles.cache.get('839532611948511272'))
 {
  console.log("Rol Var");
 }
});

```